# How to close tumblr's widgets/share/tool window after posting content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-networking, tumblr

Like most social sharing widgets, Tumblr has a post with count button that can be implemented on any site to share content to tumblr blogs. See Tumblr button widget page [here](https://www.tumblr.com/buttons). Once you click 'Post' it brings up the share window with open graph data.

BUT tumblr leaves this share window/popup page open and shows some tumblr style animation until the user closes the window. To me, this seems like a poor user experience. With this being said, once the content is 'shared' via POST button, how can I get this 'share' window closed automatically?

[Tumblr Share button documentation](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/share_button)